# KornShell call function with function transfer parameters

Tags: function, parameters, ksh, transfer

Is it possible to call a function in KornShell, which has the name as transfer parameters from a other function like:

```
function BB {
  echo "Hallo"
}

function AA {
  $1
}

AA "BB" # Here I want to give BB as transfer parameter,
        # so that $1 call my BB function
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Did you at least try it?

Comment: Yes, now it works. I have find the mistake :)

Comment: How does it work? Did you use my amswer?

Comment: You can write only the function name like AA BB. My mistake was, that I have twist two letters in the transfer function name.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the parameter in a temporary file and execute it. You will have no overhead with `chmod` and removing the tempfile when you use process substitution:

```
function AA {
  source <(echo "$1")
}
```